# Python reading json file and placing into SQLlite

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am having two problems (at least) with the below code.

My goal is to read in each tweets, parse a variable with JSON and place it into its own row in SQLlite. Of all the variables in the tweet, I am just want six of them.

I am able to read in the tweets fine (and the DB and table are created without issue).

1) I get an error with my create dictionary. It states "dictt not defined". (I had it working earlier, but did something for it not to work anymore).

2) When dictt did work, only the first tweet would load. I want all the tweets to load. So there is a problem with that loop.

Help on either?

```
#Created the DB
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#Created the table for the tweets
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tweet(created_at, id, text, source, in_reply_to_user_ID,retweet_Count)")
import json
import urllib2
#Read file and print a line
webFD = urllib2.urlopen("http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/assignment4.txt")
tweets = webFD.readlines()

#prints all tweets
for tweet in tweets:
    print tweet


#create dictionary
try:
    dictt = json.loads(tweet)
except ValueError:
    continue

#print dictionary to verify
print dictt.keys()

#print values to verify
print dictt.values()



#to load all parsed tweets into sqlite
for elt in tweets:
    currentRow = elt[:-1].split(", ")
c.execute('INSERT INTO Tweet VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        (dictt['created_at'], dictt["id"], dictt["text"], dictt['source'], dictt['in_reply_to_user_id'],
           dictt['retweet_count']))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: you didn't need : for tweet in tweets because "tweets" has string content and not JSON!

So about your codes try to get "dumps" before "loads":

```
try:
    tweets = json.dumps(tweets)
    dictt = json.loads(tweets)
except ValueError:
    pass #other codes
```

"dumps" will converts your strings as JSON.

after that you can test "dictt":

```
for i in dictt:
    print i
```

your codes can be:

```
#Created the DB
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#Created the table for the tweets
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tweet(created_at, id, text, source, in_reply_to_user_ID,retweet_Count)")
import json
import urllib2
#Read file and print a line
webFD = urllib2.urlopen("http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/assignment4.txt")
tweets = webFD.readlines()

#create dictionary
try:
    tweets = json.dumps(tweets)
    dictt = json.loads(tweets)
except ValueError:
    print "invalid data"

for i in dictt:
    try:
        print json.loads(i).get('user').get('name')
        #print json.loads(i)['user']['name']
    except ValueError:
        print "can't read"
```

After that you can save your data in the database.

Comment: That gives me a SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop. NameError: name 'dictt' is not defined

Comment: Now getting a: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys' on the loop: step. Same with values.